# How to create upstart script for grafana service?

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, upstart, grafana

In my usecase, I am trying to write an upstart script for `grafana` service. Here is my content,

```
#grafana upstart script
description "start and stop grafana server"

start on (net-device-up
and local-filesystems
and runlevel [2345])

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

console output

exec service grafana-server stop
```

But this is not woking all the time. Do I need remove any pid after stopping the `service`?

Also is this the right way to create `upstart` conf with service. Because I tried to do the same for `nginx` service. But it fails because we need to remove the `pid` after stopping the `service`.

So in general how can we write `upstart` script for `services`?

I am using amazon linux [ec2]. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just look at any script in the folder /etc/init.d and change the instructions according your your needs. The you can use the `systemctl` (or the appropiate command for your distribution) to make it run on the desired init levels